# How to use st_distance in R

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I want to find the distance between points and then filter them to only include points that are >1 km apart. I tried to use st_distance to find the initial distance between points, but I receive the same error message: "Error: object 'Lon' not found".

I have ensured that the df exists in my environment and that the variables exist within it.

```
An.TP<- An.TP %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  st_distance(Lon, Lat, by_element = TRUE)
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, Alyssa! Please see here which information you need to provide so that others can assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
That said, you could first check whether `An.TP` still is what you expect it to be, because your code takes that object, calculates something from it and assigns the results to the same name. Thus, after the first attempt, `An.TP` will be something else than before.

Comment: `sf::st_distance()` expects `sf`, `sfc` or `sfg`  objects.  When you say "df" and refer to "Lon" and "Lat" columns, I'm afraid there's a good chance that you have skipped a step where you first convert your lon/lat coordinates to point geometries, usually in a form of `sf` object. I.e something like `st_as_sf(An.TP, coords = c("Lon", "Lat"), crs = "WGS84") %>% st_distance()`  might return a distance matrix, distance from every point to all other points. Might, as we don't know what your `An.TP` object really is.